# spring-data-rest: Listed resource turned unavailable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have created a RepositoryRestResource class with ElasticSearchRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "products", path = "products")
public interface ProductSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ProductSearch, String> {
}
```

I have also configured spring-data-rest endpoint to /api and only allowed annotated classes to be available as REST resource:

```
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api
      detection-strategy: annotated
```

By making a GET request to /api I found that products can be accessed through /api/products

```
{
  "_links": {
    "products": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

However when accessing /products I will get 404

```
{
  "timestamp": 1488116396508,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/products"
}
```

The project is using Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE. Restarting the application will help occasionally but I am unable to find out the actual cause of this.

Comment: Where are you making request from? Did you put the content type header "application / json"? Did you put "no args constructor" in your entity? what does the logs show when you make the request?